# pgx is not returning rows after I do an insert

Tags: go, pgx

Im just doing an insert using the following code, and while i can see the data in the database, pgx is not returning any rows.

```
rows, err := db.Query(context.Background(), `
    INSERT INTO 
        reservation (room_id, user_id)
    VALUES 
        ($1, $2)
    `, roomId, userId)
```

I tried using QueryRow too but same thing, no rows are returned. Can anyone tell me where Im going wrong?

Comment: You need to add the `RETURNING` clause to the SQL string. See https://postgresql.org/docs/14/interactive/dml-returning.html for more details.

Comment: Cool. that did the trick. thanks